# How to change horizontal input to vertical output

Tags: unix, grep, cut

I am using UNIX Korn shell. I am trying to create a program in Unix that will search a text file which is shown below:

```
Last Name:First Name:City:State:Class:Semester Enrolled:Year First Enrolled

Gilman:Randy:Manhattan:KS:Junior:Spring:2010
Denton:Jacob:Rochester:NY:Senoir:Fall:2009
Goodman:Joshua:Warren:MI:Freshman:Summer:2014
Davidson:Blair:Snohomish:WA:Sophmore:Fall:2013
Anderson:Neo:Seattle:WA:Senoir:Spring:2008
Beckman:John:Ft. Polk:LA:Freshman:Spring:2014
```

Then take that line and cut it out and display it vertically. So if I search Gilman. It would produce:

```
Gilman
Randy
Manhattan
KS
Junior
Spring
2010
```

However included in this I should also be able to produce the following layout:

```
Last Name: Gilman
First Name: Randy
City: Manhattan
State: KS
Class: Junior
Semester Enrolled: Spring
Year First Enrolled: 2010
```

Now I have figured out most of it which I will display in my code below:

```
cat<<MENULIST
                         A - Add Student Information 
                         D - Delete Student Information
                         M - Modify Student Information
                         I - Inquiry on a Student
                         X - Exit

MENULIST

    echo -en '\n'
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "                      Pleasa choose one of the following:                      "

    #take input from operation

    read choice

    case $choice in
        a|A) ;; 
        d|D) ;;
        m|M) ;;
        i|I)   
            #Create Inguiry Message
            clear
            echo "                                 Record Inquiry                                 "
            echo -en '\n'
            echo -en '\n'
            echo "What is the last name of the person"
            #Gather search parameter
            read last_name
            grep -i "$last_name" $1 | cut -f 1-7 -d ':' ;;


        x|X) echo "The program is ending" ; exit 0;;
        *) echo -en '\n' ;echo "Not an acceptable entry." ;echo "Please press enter to try again"; read JUNK | tee -a $2 ; continue
    esac
```

I am just really having trouble on redirecting input to the proper output. There is much more to the program but this is the relevant portion for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok the final answer is shown below:

```
while IFS=: read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 rest ; do
                case "$c1" in
                    "$last_name" )
                        echo -e "Last Name: $c1\nFirst Name: $c2\nCity: $c3\nState: $c4\nClass: $c5\nSemester Enrolled: $c6\nYear First Enrolled: $c7\n\n"
                    ;;
                esac
            done < $1
```

This performed the intended outcome correctly thank you everyone for your help. I still have some other questions but I will make a new topic for that so it doesn't get to jumbled together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your line

```
 grep -i "$last_name" $1 | cut -f 1-7 -d ':' ;;
```

with

```
  awk -F: -vnameMatch="$last_name" \
   '$1==nameMatch{
      printf("LastName:%s\nFirstName:%s\nCity:%s\nState:%s\nClass:%s\nSemester Enrolled:%s\nYear First Enrolled:%s\n\n", \
             $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
    }' $1 
;;
```

It's pretty much the same idea in ksh.

```
while IFS=: read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 rest ; do
  case "$c1" in 
    "$last_name" )
        printf "LastName:%s\nFirstName:%s\nCity:%s\nState:%s\nClass:%s\nSemester Enrolled:%s\nYear First Enrolled:%s\n\n",
             "$c1" "$c2" "$c3" "$c4" "$c5" "$c6" "$c7"
      ;;
   esac
  done < $1
```

I think I've got all the syntax right, but don't have the energy tonight to test :-/ ... If you can use this, and there are problems, post a comment and I'll clean it up.

IHTH.

**EDIT:**

```
#Case statement for conducting an inquiry of the file
        i|I)   
            #Create Inguiry Message
            clear
            echo "                                 Record Inquiry                                 "
            echo -en '\n'
            echo -en '\n'
            echo "What is the last name of the person:"
            #Gather search parameter
            read last_name
            while IFS=: read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 rest ; do
                case "$c1" in
                    "$last_name" )
                        printf "Last Name:%s\nFirst Name:%s\nCity:%s\nState:%s\nClass:%s\nSemester Enrolled:%s\nYear First Enrolled:%s\n\n", "$c1", "$c2", "$c3", "$c4", "$c5", "$c6", "$c7"
                    ;;
                esac
            done < $2
        #Case statement for ending the program          
        x|X) echo "The program is ending" ; exit 0;;
```

The error message is:

*./asg7s: line 26: syntax error at line 93: `)' unexpected*

Line 93 is

```
x|X) echo "The program is ending" ; exit 0;;
```

Kind of weird because I didn't mess with that part of the program so I know it has to be something in the portion I changed.

RLG

Adding something extra so I can save RLG edit without other's "approval"

Comment: I updated the code, however I get an error code in a portion of the program still. I will edit it on your post to show you.

Comment: @RandyGilman : you don't a have a `;;` closing off your `i|I )` case. (Placed after the `done < $2` line). Fix that and see if you get a different error message. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
last_name="Gilman"

awk -F: -v name="$last_name" 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) h[i]=$i} $1==name {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print h[i]FS,$i}' file
Last Name: Gilman
First Name: Randy
City: Manhattan
State: KS
Class: Junior
Semester Enrolled: Spring
Year First Enrolled: 2010
```

It stores the first line in array `h` (header).
Then if it finds the pattern, print out array and data.

Answer (score 0):

Here I post an alternative to a `shell` script, in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -F':' -lne '
    BEGIN { $name = pop; }
    $. == 1 and do { @header = @F; next; };
    next if m/^\s*$/;
    if ( $F[0] eq $name ) { 
        for ( $i = 0; $i < @F; $i++ ) { 
            printf qq|%s: %s\n|, $header[$i], $F[$i];
        }   
        exit 0;
    }   
' infile Gilman
```

It uses `-F` swith to split fields with colon, `-l` removes last newline character and `-n` opens input file and process it line by line.

The script accepts two arguments, but I extract the last one before processing assuming it's the name you want to search.

First line is saved in an array called `@header` and for next lines it compares first field, and in a match, prints each header followed by each field of current line and aborts the program.

It yields:

```
Last Name: Gilman
First Name: Randy
City: Manhattan
State: KS
Class: Junior
Semester Enrolled: Spring
Year First Enrolled: 2010
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do with korn, I have explicit instructions that say can't be anything but korn?

Comment: @RandyGilman: I suppose so, but my `korn` skill is not good enough, so simply wait to some gurus come in and help you with the tool you want.